# How to highlight column in table angular 6

Tags: css, html-table, angular6, angular7, highlight

Im trying to highlight entire column in table on hover.

Can someone help me how I can achieve this in angular2+

I need exactly like the below image

[image]

reference image

Answer (score 2):

You can use :before and :after

```
td:hover::before {
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    left: -5000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10000px;
    z-index: -2;
}


td:hover::after {
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '';
    height: 10000px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Full working example in Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0vm7pkj4/1/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to have it so that you can click a row and have that row highlighted, similar for a column.

If so, you could try the following:

Create an array for columns that's equal in length to the number of columns, same for rows.
`tableRowHighlights: Array<boolean> = [];
tableColumnHighlights: Array<boolean> = [];`
Fill them with false values, then, when generating your table, assign each cell a css class that will highlight it based on the row or column index:
`[class.colSelected]="tableColumnHighlights[4]"`

Now, when `tableColumnHighlights[4]` is true, every cell that has 4 specified will gain the `colSelected` class which will have your highlight.

Then you can set, on each cell, a click listener that alternates the status:
`(click)="tableColumnHighlights[4] = !tablecolumnHighlights[4]"`

Do the same thing for rows. You could also put the listener only on the thead elements for columns if you wished.

Hopefully this is what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use hover effect through your table Class, hope this would help

```
.MyTable td:hover {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: That would only highlight the cell. I think the OP wants the column and row

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code I THink It's Useful For You.

```js
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  var testCtrl = this;
  testCtrl.data = [
    {col1: '0342', col2: '234', col3: '642356', col4: 'Black', col5: 'Item 1', col6: true},
    {col1: '0533', col2: '775', col3: '223542', col4: 'Green', col5: 'Item 2', col6: true},
    {col1: '0973', col2: '284', col3: '997546', col4: 'Purple', col5: 'Item 3', col6: false},
    {col1: '0125', col2: '997', col3: '285734', col4: 'Orange', col5: 'Item 4', col6: false},
    {col1: '0432', col2: '132', col3: '996445', col4: 'White', col5: 'Item 5', col6: true}
  ];
  
  testCtrl.structure = [
    {field: 'col1', display: 'Col 1', class: 'col1'},
    {field: 'col2', display: 'Col 2', class: 'col2'},
    {field: 'col3', display: 'Col 3', class: 'col3'},
    {field: 'col4', display: 'Col 4', class: 'col4'},
    {field: 'col5', display: 'Col 5', class: 'col5'},
    {field: 'col6', display: 'Col 6', class: 'col6'}
  ];
  
  drag = event => {
    var index = angular.element(event.target).scope().$index;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("dragIndex", index);
  };
   
  drop = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dropElement = angular.element(event.target);
    var dragIndex = event.dataTransfer.getData("dragIndex"); 
    var dropIndex = dropElement.scope().$index;
    
    var column = testCtrl.structure[dragIndex];
    testCtrl.structure.splice(dragIndex, 1);
    
    var insertIndex = dragIndex > dropIndex ? dropIndex : dropIndex - 1;
    if (event.offsetX > dropElement[0].scrollWidth / 2)
      insertIndex++;
    
    testCtrl.structure.splice(insertIndex, 0, column);
    $scope.$digest();
  };
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

th, td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5,
.col6 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.col6 {
  text-align: center;
}

.col1:hover,
.col2:hover,
.col3:hover,
.col4:hover,
.col5:hover,
.col6:hover {
  background-color: #DAA520;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController as testCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in testCtrl.structure" 
            class="{{header.class}}" 
            draggable="true"
            ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
            ondragstart="drag(event);"
            ondrop="drop(event);">
                {{header.display}}
        </th>      
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in testCtrl.data">
        <td ng-repeat="body in testCtrl.structure" ng-switch="body.field" class="{{body.class}}">
          <div ng-switch-when="col6">
            <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-file': row[body.field], 'fa-file-o': !row[body.field]}"></i>
          </div>
          <div ng-switch-default>{{row[body.field]}}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```